# Page keep reloading after redirecting in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I need to redirect users who are not authorised to enter certain routes. Here is part of my code:

```
$http.post(apiURL + '/all' , {
        token: localStorage.getItem('token')
    }).success(function (data) {
            $rootScope.roomPictures = data;
    }).error(function (error, status) {
            if (status === 401) {
                window.location.href = 'auth.html';
            }
    });
```

The angular actually redirects to auth.html, but then browser keeps refreshing and refreshing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's a chance your auth.html has a controller attached to it that is trying to redirect again and is causing an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: Also, I would consider using AngularJS' built in `$location` and `$window` libraries for redirecting.

Comment: @BenBeck well in auth.html is the same controller... so that might be the problem I think...

Comment: post the auth code please

Comment: @Karim you mean the code inside auth.html?

Comment: I think you just answered your own problem there, @marek

Comment: @Karim Yeah. Now I added new controller in auth.html and after redirecting everything is alright :)

Comment: @Karim Thanks for you help, but I've already solved this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that in auth.html I had the same controller as I had in the current .html file. After creating new controller and adding it to the auth.html file everything works as it should.